# Assigning roles via mention the user in Discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm creating a bot for my discord server and I am trying to make a command that adds a role to someone by using the command '.join' followed by a mention of the user you are trying to give the role to. below is the code I'm using for the command. It doesn't work

```
@client.command(help='Lets you join the specified faction. the user variable is who you are adding to the faction (type it as a mention. eg. @GlitchedData64)')
async def join(ctx, user, rolerequest):                                                         
    author = ctx.message.author
    rolelist = [r.mention for r in author.roles if r != ctx.guild.default_role]
    roles = ", ".join(rolelist)

    if admintoken in roles or ownertoken in roles:
        if 'enders' in rolerequest or 'Enders' in rolerequest:
            if enderstoken in roles:
                await ctx.send(f'{user}, is already in that faction')
                
            elif krypticstoken in roles:
                await ctx.send(f'{user}, is already in a faction.\nTo join another faction they must leave the one they are currently in')
                
            elif dotstoken in roles:
                await ctx.send(f'{user}, is already in a faction.\nTo join another faction they must leave the one they are currently in')

            else: 
                role = discord.utils.get(user.guild.roles, name="Enders")
                await discord.Member.add_roles(user, role)
                await ctx.send(f'{user.mention} has joined the Enders Faction')
                print(f'{user} has joined the Enders Faction')
                
        elif 'kryptics' in rolerequest or 'Kryptics' in rolerequest:
            if krypticstoken in roles:
                await ctx.send(f'{user}, is already in that faction')                           
            
            elif enderstoken in roles:
                await ctx.send(f'{user}, is already in a faction.\nTo join another faction they must leave the one they are currently in')
                
            elif dotstoken in roles:
                await ctx.send(f'{user}, is already in a faction.\nTo join another faction they must leave the one they are currently in')
                
            else:
                role = discord.utils.get(user.guild.roles, name="kryptics")
                await discord.Member.add_roles(user, role)
                await ctx.send(f'{user.mention} has joined the Kryptics Faction')
                print(f'{user} has joined the Kryptics Faction')
                
        elif 'dots' in rolerequest or 'Dots' in rolerequest:
            if dotstoken in roles:
                await ctx.send(f'{user}, is already in that faction')
            
            elif krypticstoken in roles:
                await ctx.send(f'{user}, is already in a faction.\nTo join another faction they must leave the one they are currently in')
                
            elif enderstoken in roles:
                await ctx.send(f'{user}, is already in a faction.\nTo join another faction they must leave the one they are currently in')
            
            else:
                role = discord.utils.get(user.guild.roles, name="Dots")
                await discord.Member.add_roles(user, role)
                await ctx.send(f'{user.mention} has joined the Dots Faction')
                print(f'{user} has joined the Dots Faction')
                
        else:
            await ctx.send(f"I'm affraid that faction doesn't exist. you can create it with '.createfaction' followed by the name")

    else:
        await ctx.send(f'This command is not available to Non-administrator users')
```

I'm fairly new to making bots so if it's a really obvious answer pls tell (also I'm using the rewrite branch of discord.py)

Answer (score 0):

The first mistake I see is on the function call, you are passing the wrong parameters.

On discord.py, your command should point to the specific `Member` and `Role`, which means it should look something like this:

```
async def join(self, ctx, user: discord.Member, role: discord.Role):
```

Still, it would be helpful if you could tell us your output log or why your code is not working, instead of just copypasting your code and asking for us to fix it.

EDIT: Doing a bot function to add X role to Y member would be as easy as:

```
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def giverole(ctx, user: discord.Member, role: discord.Role):
    await user.add_roles(role)
    await ctx.send(f"hey {ctx.author.name}, {user.name} has been giving a role called: {role.name}")
```

Comment: i aplologize if i didn't explain well enough. there is no error displayed when the command is entered. it just does nothing

Comment: Thank you very much. As I said in my question I am new to making discord bots and python in general so sorry for my lack of knowledge. i have used your code and it works. Thanks

Comment: To be honest I do not understand much of the stuff you are doing (or comparing) in your code. Check my last edition for a easy way of doing what you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
@client.command(help='Lets you join the specified faction. the user variable is who you are adding to the faction (type it as a mention. eg. @GlitchedData64)')
async def join(ctx, user: discord.Member, rolerequest):                                                         
    author = ctx.message.author
    rolelist = [r.mention for r in author.roles if r != ctx.guild.default_role]
    roles = ", ".join(rolelist)

    if admintoken in roles or ownertoken in roles:
        if 'enders' in rolerequest or 'Enders' in rolerequest:
            if enderstoken in roles:
                await ctx.send(f'{user}, is already in that faction')
                
            elif krypticstoken in roles:
                await ctx.send(f'{user}, is already in a faction.\nTo join another faction they must leave the one they are currently in')
                
            elif dotstoken in roles:
                await ctx.send(f'{user}, is already in a faction.\nTo join another faction they must leave the one they are currently in')

            else: 
                role = discord.utils.get(user.guild.roles, name="Enders")
                await user.add_roles(role)
                await ctx.send(f'{user.mention} has joined the Enders Faction')
                print(f'{user} has joined the Enders Faction')
                
        elif 'kryptics' in rolerequest or 'Kryptics' in rolerequest:
            if krypticstoken in roles:
                await ctx.send(f'{user}, is already in that faction')                           
            
            elif enderstoken in roles:
                await ctx.send(f'{user}, is already in a faction.\nTo join another faction they must leave the one they are currently in')
                
            elif dotstoken in roles:
                await ctx.send(f'{user}, is already in a faction.\nTo join another faction they must leave the one they are currently in')
                
            else:
                role = discord.utils.get(user.guild.roles, name="kryptics")
                await user.add_roles(role)
                await ctx.send(f'{user.mention} has joined the Kryptics Faction')
                print(f'{user} has joined the Kryptics Faction')
                
        elif 'dots' in rolerequest or 'Dots' in rolerequest:
            if dotstoken in roles:
                await ctx.send(f'{user}, is already in that faction')
            
            elif krypticstoken in roles:
                await ctx.send(f'{user}, is already in a faction.\nTo join another faction they must leave the one they are currently in')
                
            elif enderstoken in roles:
                await ctx.send(f'{user}, is already in a faction.\nTo join another faction they must leave the one they are currently in')
            
            else:
                role = discord.utils.get(user.guild.roles, name="Dots")
                await user.add_roles(role)
                await ctx.send(f'{user.mention} has joined the Dots Faction')
                print(f'{user} has joined the Dots Faction')
                
        else:
            await ctx.send(f"I'm affraid that faction doesn't exist. you can create it with '.createfaction' followed by the name")

    else:
        await ctx.send(f'This command is not available to Non-administrator users')
```

You shouldn't be doing `discord.Member.add_roles(user, role)`.